# How to fix Samsung Note 3 SM-N900 bootloader loop?

Tags: adb, 5.0-lollipop, boot-loop

My Samsung Note 3 SM-N900 got fully discharged and now it's stuck at the samsung logo when I power it back on.

Things that I have tried to fix my mobile:

1. Wiped the Cache partition from the recovery mode.
2. Used platform tools for adb recovery, but the device is not recognized in the PC probably because USB debugging was not on.
3. Soft reset using Home and power button.
4. Fully recharged the mobile, changed the battery as well.

I have a lot of important data which I don't want to erase. The last option left with me is to factory reset my device which would result in data loss. Is there any other way to fix the device without losing the data?

Comment: See if you can boot into [safe mode](https://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-27712) and copy data to PC and then do factory reset

Comment: You said you made wipe from recovery. Do you have custom or stock recovery?

Comment: @Suncatcher I have stock recovery.

Comment: @beeshyams I am not able to go into the safe mode either.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways of recovering you data:

1. Boot into fastboot and try to flash custom recovery (like TWRP). It allows making partition backups, which you can open on PC later.

   ```
   fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
   ```
2. Try to boot into temporary custom recovery and do the same (full partition backup). However, this depends on device and can be not available for Samsung Note.

   Check [this](http://sero7forum.com/sero-7-root-hack-mod-and-development/fastboot-to-a-temporary-recovery-flash-backup-or-restore/) and [this](https://irisbuddies.blogspot.com/2017/01/temporary-recovery-boot-into-custom.html) tutorial.

What concerns fixing the tablet in general from bootloop, it depends on what you've done/what have happened, and probably cannot be achieved without loosing your data. To be on the safe side, it's always preferable to do the backup prior to any manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

Do what Suncatcher suggest,

And / or...

Install Phliz cuatom recovery via download mode to do full partition backup to your external card
(Philz makes good backup, results in folder clockworkmod)

Then change the recovery, install TWRP custom recovery via download mode and go to file manager feature to copy all your files from internal memory to external card
You can mount the system partition also to browse and copy files
(TWRP good at this)

Backup all your copy and partition backup from external card to your PC

Back to your phone with file manager in TWRP,
Go to /data/system/sync
Rename folder /sync to /sync.old

Then back to /data/app
Delete or rename to .old the apk that you suspect too hard to load when boot up

Then rename that folder /data/app to /data/app.old

Then reboot the system

You will find your phone successfully boot with factory only applications
There will be your last sms, contacts, dial logs with no last applications you've had

If you want to get your last applications, reboot to recovery (TWRP) go to advance - file manager
Delete the /data/app
Then rename /data/app.old back to /data/app

Wipe dalvik cache

Repair partiton one by one (in wipe - advance) feature

Do the renaming and wiping steps carefully and get focus
(well, you still have backups in your PC, right?)

Then reboot the system

You have to plug in your devices to charger while waiting the phone boot up. It can take up to one hour to successfully boot depend on how many applications to load

You will find all your applications back on stage but with no logins

Hope that could help